# Css style is not working for ul uib-pagination. ui-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

When I use the version of bootstrap(3.3.1). It is working good and I have this result.

[image]

When I use last version (4.3.1) it is working but I have this css result

[image]

My html code

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul uib-pagination 
        ng-model="currentPage"
        total-items="totalItems"
        max-size="maxSize"  
        boundary-links="true">
      </ul>
</div>
```

I need last version to work.

I use angular-ui-bootstrap/2.3.0

Comment: `ui-bootstrap` was not made to utilize bootstrap 4. you can use [this](https://github.com/Morgul/ui-bootstrap4) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

this is my first post, I am also resolved with this problem, I have solved with the following, I hope it works, if you have to do it more automatically, please let me know, regards!

```
<pre>

    [ul.pagination
    {
      border:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
      border-radius:5px;    
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-page 
    {
      border-right:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
      padding-left:15px;
      padding-right:15px;
    }

    li.pagination-page.ng-scope.active
    {
      background-color:#28a745;
    }

    li.pagination-page.ng-scope a
    {   
      color:#999;
    }


    li.pagination-page.ng-scope.active a
    {   
      color:#FFF;
      font-weight:bold;
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-prev
    {
      border-right:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
      padding:10px;
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-prev a
    {
      color:#F90;   
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-next
    {
      border-right:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
      padding:10px;
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-next a
    {
      color:#F90;   
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-first
    {
      border-right:solid 1px #CCCCCC;
      padding:10;       
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-first a
    {
      color:#F90;   
    }


    ul.pagination li.pagination-last
    {
      padding:10px;
    }

    ul.pagination li.pagination-last a
    {
      color:#F90;   
    }

    ul.pagination li
    {   
      padding:10px;
    }][1]

</pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, I coulnd`t find any wich can help us. Thanks for you answer, I use it and it is work!

Answer (score 0):

Final Solution, Modify ui-boostrap.min.js template pagination.html with -->

Work with Css default boostrap , in my case 4.2.1

https://github.com/Morgul/ui-bootstrap4/blob/e44b6d6f2e3bd8396099b83eea29bd4086b78689/template/pagination/pagination.html